# Python: turtle goto() command

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, goto

My assignment asks me to code a graphical representation of some nested squares varying in size from 20-80, like this:

[image]

After creating the first square, I need to move position to the start of the next square. I use the `goto()` command for this. My problem is the `goto()` command as I use two variables for the horizontal and vertical inputs but only one of them works at a time--I need them both to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#Draw a set of nested squares, increasing in size
from turtle import *

number_of_shapes = 4

for shape in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1):
    #Draw a square
    for sides in range(1,5):
        forward(20 + shape * 10)
        right(90)

#Move to position of next square
    penup()
    goto(shape * 10, shape * 10)
    pendown()
```

Comment: To format your code correctly, copy-paste it from a source file into the question box, then select everything you pasted (including the parts that look okay in the preview) and hit Ctrl-K.

Comment: What do you mean by "only one of them works at a time"? And what two variables are you referring to? You seem to be using `shape` to control both horizontal and vertical movement.

Comment: I can roughly deduce what the commands `forward`, `right`, and `goto` do, but in order to find the reason why "only one of them works at a time", I would need more info. Like, what is the implementation of the `goto`? Which variables does it affect? Why are you using 1-indexing? etc. :)

Comment: @RafazZ: The `from turtle import *` obscures the fact that `forward`, `right`, `goto` are all [turtle functions](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.goto).

Comment: Oh I see -- my bad :)) still doesn't answer the 1-indexing lolol ;)

Comment: The squares are supposed to increase by 20 each time. 'shape' is the variables I was referring to. the turtle needs to move position each time, so as the squares increase in size the horizontal and vertical increase also. Apologies if I'm not explaining well I'm new to python.

Comment: If you want them centered, you need to move half as much and the x needs to move in the negative: `goto(-(shape * 5), shape * 5)`

Comment: Thank- you! @JohnnyMopp I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the great things about Python is that it is easy to test small pieces of code in the interpreter. Let's use the interpreter to check the length of the sides:

```
In [82]: number_of_shapes = 4

In [83]: for shape in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1):
   ....:     print(20 + shape * 10)
30
40
50
60
```

Oops. Now we can clearly see `forward(20 + shape * 10)` isn't going to make the sides have lengths 20, 40, 60, and 80. Notice that `(20 + shape * 10)` makes the side lengths increment by 10. We want to increment by 20, so use `(20 + shape * 20)` instead:

```
In [84]: for shape in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1):
   ....:     print(20 + shape * 20)
   ....: 
40
60
80
100
```

Oops, I got it wrong. No problem, we just need to decrement the whole thing by 20:

```
In [85]: for shape in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1):
   ....:     print(shape * 20)
   ....: 
20
40
60
80
```

Ah, much better.

---

So now the code looks like this:

```
import turtle

number_of_shapes = 4

for shape in range(1, number_of_shapes+1):
    #Draw a square
    for sides in range(4):
        turtle.forward(20 + shape * 20)
        turtle.right(90)

    #Move to position of next square
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(shape * 10, shape * 10)
    turtle.pendown()
turtle.mainloop()
```

[image]

When you run this code, notice that the turtle starts each square at the top left corner
and starts drawing to the right.

---

Now let's think about the `goto(shape * 10, shape * 10)` statement. Where is it taking us? Let's use the interpreter to find out:

```
In [87]: for shape in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1):
   ....:     print(shape * 10, shape * 10)
   ....: 
10 10
20 20
30 30
40 40
```

Comparing these coordinates with the result above, you can see that the turtle is being moved up and to the right. The top left corner of each square is starting a little higher and a little to the right. Instead, we want the top left corner of each new square to start a little higher and *to the left*:

```
In [88]: for shape in range(1, number_of_shapes + 1):
   ....:     print(-shape * 10, shape * 10)
   ....: 
-10 10
-20 20
-30 30
-40 40
```

Let's see what happens now:

[image]

Bingo.

---

By the way, mixing relative commands like `left` and `right` and `forward` with absolute commands like `goto` requires... coordination. The math is finicky. 
If you stick with purely relative commands, you don't have to think hard about getting the `goto` coordinate formulas correct:

```
turtle.penup()
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(10)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(10)
turtle.left(180)
turtle.pendown()
```

The advantage of using purely relative commands is that now you can place the turtle anywhere you want, with any initial heading, and still draw nested squares:

```
import turtle

number_of_shapes = 4
turtle.setheading(45)
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(20, 50)
turtle.pendown()
for shape in range(1, number_of_shapes+1):
    #Draw a square
    for sides in range(4):
        turtle.forward(20 + shape * 20)
        turtle.right(90)

    #Move to position of next square
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(10)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(10)
    turtle.left(180)
    turtle.pendown()
turtle.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: `range(number_of_shapes)` produces an image more similar to the OP's example than does `range(1, number_of_shapes+1)`.

Comment: I didn't think to use the interpreter to check the values. I will definitely use this in the future.  @unutbu

Answer (score 0):

This simple geometric shape is a perfect example of how *stamping* can be *simpler* and *faster* than *drawing*:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

NUMBER_OF_SHAPES = 4
CURSOR_SIZE = 20  # cursor sized relative to this starting size

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle('square', visible=False)
turtle.color('black', 'white')  # pencolor, fillcolor
turtle.penup()

for shape in range(NUMBER_OF_SHAPES - 1, -1, -1):  # from large to small
    turtle.shapesize((20 + shape * 20) / CURSOR_SIZE)
    turtle.stamp()

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

Just like with *drawing*, we can rotate the image simply adding:

```
turtle.setheading(45)
```

or a `turtle.left(45)` or `turtle.right(45)`:

[image]

but unlike *drawing*, we can also take advantage of other turtle cursor graphic operations that aren't implemented by turtle for *drawing*.  For example, *shear*:

```
turtle.shearfactor(0.5)
```

[image]

I'm sure you're expected to use *drawing* to solve this problem but as you move onto your own programs, keep *stamping* in mind as a *simpler*, *faster*, *flexible* solution for some simple geometrical shapes.

Comment: You're right I had to use drawing to make the squares. But I will make use of this in any other projects.

Answer (score -1):

---

```
import turtle
from turtle import *
speed()
a=50
x=-15
y=15
for i in range(7):
  for n in range (4):
    forward(a)
    right(90)
  penup()
  goto(x,y)
  pd()
  a+=10
  x-=5
  y+=5
```

---

Comment: hi, it would be great if you provide a explaination also